# Сложение цифр числа. Количество цифр в числе

Tags: haskell

Только начал изучать haskell. В задаче требуется вывести двухэлементный кортеж, в котором первый элемент - это сумма цифр числа, а второй - количество цифр в числе.
Кое-что написал, но не работает - компилятор выводит много ошибок связанных с типами данных.

```
sum'n'count x   | x == 0 = (0, 1)
                | otherwise = (a x, b x)
                    where 
                        b x | x < 10 = 1
                            | otherwise = 1 + b (div (x 10))
                        a x | x > 10 = a (div (x 10)) + mod (x 10)  
                            | otherwise = x
```

Comment: `div x 10` вместо `div (x 10)`, аналогично с `mod`. Кроме этого есть небольшая ошибка в функции `a`

Comment: @extrn спасибо, все заработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и написали в комментариях, ошибка была в лишних скобках для функций `mod` и `div`. Такой код будет работать правильно:

```html
sum'n'count :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
sum'n'count x   | x == 0 = (0, 1)
                | otherwise = (a x, b x)
                    where 
                        b x | abs x < 10 = 1 
                            | otherwise = 1 + b (div x 10)
                        a x | abs x < 10 = x
                            | otherwise = a (div (abs x) 10) + mod (abs x) 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я чуть поправил, как смог, так как такой же новичек в программировании) Для вычисления длинны числа использовал замену на 1 и затем сумму. Это позволяет считать и такие тесты: "-001". А для суммы не хватало условия для отрицательных чисел меньше 10, тоже добавил.

```
sum'n'count x = (sumX x, lengthX x)
   where 
      lengthX x = sum[1|_<-(show (abs x))]
      sumX x | (abs x) < 10 = abs x
             | otherwise    = sumX (div (abs x) 10) + mod (abs x) 10
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]